# With docker-compose, how do I keep a container running even if the "command" fails?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command, containers

I’m using docker 20.10.12 on Mac Big Sur.  I have the following snippet in my docker-compose file

```
  web:
    restart: "no"
    build: ../my-dir
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    expose:
      - '3000'
    command: /bin/sh -c "foreman start -f myprocfile”
    volumes:
    - ../cfs-web/:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The problem is if my “command” fails, the container dies and I’m unable to exec into it.  If I change restart to

```
Restart: “always”
```

The container continuously restarts and fails, but I’m still unable to exec in because it seems like the container is getting re-created each time.  Is there a way to keep the container up even if the command fails (so I can login and potentially run some other commands)?

Comment: You can `docker-compose run sh` to get an interactive shell in a new container based on that service specification, but replacing the `command:` with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities. Basically you just want to wait indefinitely (or long enough for you to exec in to the container) after your main command failed. Here are some examples:

- `command: /bin/sh -c "foreman start -f myprocfile || sleep 2073600”`
- `command: /bin/sh -c "foreman start -f myprocfile || tail -f /dev/null”`
- `command: /bin/sh -c "foreman start -f myprocfile || while :; do sleep 2073600; done"`

Obviously it's a dirty hack that blocks cpu cycles so it should only be used for local debugging.

EDIT: You might want to replace `||` with `;` in case your command doesn't actually fail but just exits successfully.